# Проблема с выполнением кода

Tags: python, классы, объекты

Не судите строго, я только начала этим заниматься. Изучая python по книге "Byte of Python", я дошла до темы 'переменные класса и объекта'. Нашла там вот этот код:

```
class Robot:
    '''Представляет робота с именем.'''
    # Переменная класса, содержащая количество роботов
    population = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        '''Инициализация данных.'''
        self.name = name
        print('(Инициализация {0})'.format(self.name))

    # При создании этой личности, робот добавляется
    # к переменной population
    Robot.population += 1

    def __del__(self):
        '''Я умираю.'''
        print('{0} уничтожаеться'.formay(self.name))

        Robot.population -= 1

        if Robot.population == 0:
            print('{0} был последним'.format(self.name))
        else:
            print('осталось {0:d} работающих роботов'.format(Robot.population))

    def sayHi(self):
        '''Приветствие робота.

        Да, они это могут'''
        print('Приветствую! Мои хозяива называют меня {0}'.format(self.name))

    def howMany():
        '''Выводит численность роботов.'''
        print('У нас {0:d} роботов'.format(Robot.population))

    howMany = staticmethod(howMany)


droid1 = Robot('R2-D2')
droid1.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

droid2 = Robot('C-3PO')
droid2.sayHi()  
Robot.howMany()

print('\nЗдесь роботы могут проделать какую-то работу.\n')

print('Роботы закончили свою работу. Давайте уничтожим их')
del droid1
del droid2
```

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка. Прошу подскажите кто может...

Comment: У кода есть продолжение, просто по какой-то причине я не смогла туда его вписать. Вот:           
droid1 = Robot('R2-D2')
droid1.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

droid2 = Robot('C-3PO')
droid2.sayHi()
Robot.howMany()

print('\nЗдесь роботы могут проделать какую-то работу.\n')

print('Роботы закончили свою работу. Давайте уничтожим их')
del droid1
del droid2

Comment: Почему вы решили, что есть какая-то ошибка?

Comment: Потому-что после компиляции компилятор выдает такую ошибку:                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/objvar.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Robot:
  File "D:/python/objvar.py", line 13, in Robot
    Robot.population += 1
NameError: name 'Robot' is not defined

Comment: Проверьте свой код, наверняка неправильно перепечатано. Кстати, в ошибке написано в чем именно она заключается и в какой строке.

Comment: Да! Вы правы! Просто пересмотрела код на ошибки и нашла несколько опечаток и неправильных отступов. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Попробуйте в следующий раз `pylint`. https://www.pylint.org/